# Storing sliding window of time-series data on disk

Tags: go, time-series, store, leveldb

I've written a server which consumes a live stream of chronologically ordered events (time-series) and maintains a sliding window (24h) of the data. It only supports one type of query:

```
get N seconds of events starting at timestamp T
```

I'm currently using [leveldb](https://github.com/google/leveldb) with unix timestamps as the keys. This works alright but, since leveldb is a [LSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-structured_merge-tree), the deletes are expensive (tombstones).

Can anyone suggest a better solution/datasore for this use case?

- The data is too big to store in memory
- The server is written in Go

Comment: You're looking for a different StackExchange for this question, clearly falls under the 'opinion based' category which seems to offend round these parts ;p

Comment: as evanmcdonnal said, this isn't the place for library recommendations, *but*... you could always go back to the tried-and-true constant-space time-series db: `rrd`. MongoDB also has "Capped collections" which support high volume inserts with fixed storage size.

Comment: Part of the problem is that I don't need constant space, I need a window of time. How much data shows up in that window can vary drastically. 

I don't want a library recommendation as much as I want a data-structure recommendation. If it was in memory I'd use a circular buffer of buckets. I want something like that, but on disk.

Comment: To me it sounds like a use for kafka. At least, in my limited experience working in data collection, I've seen kafka used for this type of thing. I believe the main features your want are inherit in it's design.

Comment: That's a little more complex than what can reduced to a "data structure", but if this is in-order, write-once data, something as simple as a log file per bucket could suffice. You might want to look at [boltdb](https://github.com/boltdb/bolt) where you can store and delete in buckets (bonus, it's a Go library).

Comment: +1 for what JimB said. Use files, or directories if too many files, to slice up your time series. Then 'rm -fr' the expired range.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is just always have 2 leveldb's  - for the current day and the previous one. And you write to the current only.

And once a day you just

```
delete(previous)
previous := current
current := new()
```

You may then save almost 2 days instead of one, but rotation is really easy.